# org.mongodb.driver.connection : Exception thrown during connection pool background maintenance task com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

We have warm in our log, it not an error but is uncorfortable to try to location the problem in our applicattion. We have 3 environment but only produce in one, please could you  help us to eliminate this warm

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally we modified the log trace for mongodBD driver and this warm has disappeared. In case it helps we put in the application.yamml this code.

logging.level.org.mongodb.driver: ERROR

Best Regards